# Побитовое ИЛИ в Go

Tags: golang

Код:

```go
func (p *packet) readValInt() (int32, error) {
 i := 0
 var res int32
 var read byte

 for ok := true; ok; ok = ((read & 0b10000000) != 0) {
    read, err := p.readByte()
    if(err != nil) {
        return 0, err
    }

    value := (read & 0b01111111)
    res |= (value << (7 * i))
    i++

    if(i > 5) {
        return 0, errors.New("VarInt is too big")
    }
 }

 return res, nil
}
```

Лог компилятора:

```
invalid operation: mismatched types int32 and byte
```

Ругается на строчку:

```go
res |= (value << (7 * i))
```

Что мне с этим делать? Я также заметил что компилятор не ругается, если заменить int32 на uint32

Comment: потому что `(value << (7 * i))` будет какой нибудь uint8, а res у вас int32. вам надо явно делать преобразование , например `res |= int32(value << (7 * i))`

Comment: @SeniorPomidor большое спасибо, помогло!

Comment: всегда рады помочь

Comment: Увеличиваете i на 7 сразу, а не на 1, и от умножения избавитесь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

проблема в том, что у вас `value << (7 * i)` является `unit8`, а `res` - это `int32`. Неявно присваивать нельзя, поэтому компилятор ругается. Вам нужно явно указывать тип следующим образом

```
res |= int32(value << (7 * i))
```